# Lines became pixelated in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, bug

I don't know what caused this. Suddenly last week, lines became so pixelated in Illustrator (like the photo below). It happens with all files including old ones. The software hasn't changed.

This happens when I use pen tool to draw a simple line and it become worse with using stroke width profiles or some other editions

What am I to do?

[image]

Comment: This is a question for Super User and could use some more detail

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: yes it happens with all files, old ones too. And the software is still the same. This happens when i use pen tool to draw a simple line, and it become worse with using stroke width profiles or some other editions .. (if this what you meant by a particular line style).

Comment: what @ZachSaucier means is that you should ask on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Go to <kbd>View > Pixel Preview</kbd> and uncheck it, or press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.